# Drow multiple boxplots of 2 differents variables (same parameter values) in one plot and associating it to a facet grid plot

Tags: r, boxplot, facet-grid

I would like to draw a facet plot of box plots of 2 variables (for comparison) in the same plots. However I'm not able to do it. I could do the same thing with a geom_point of the different quantiles of the box plot (min, Q1,median, Q3, max) but not box plots.
Here is a example of data structure (preparation of it)

```
#data construction
Treatement=rep(c("R2","R6"), each = 120)

Parameters_base1=rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 20) #3 parameters
Parameters_base2=rep(Parameters_base1,2) # outputs
Parameters=rep(Parameters_base2,2) # Treatments

Par_val_prep1=rep(c(1,2,3,4), each = 5)  #1 parameter
Par_val_prep2=rep(Par_val_prep1,3) #3 parameters
Par_val_prep3=rep(Par_val_prep2,2) # outputs
Parameters_values=rep(Par_val_prep3,2) # Treatments

Percentage_prep1=c(5,10,20,40,60,1,20,30,50,70,2,15,22,43,66,10,40,60,80,89) 
Percentage_prep2=c(2,30,45,77,90,0,3,15,40,55,4,11,28,44,50,7,19,33,47,68)
Percentage_prep3=c(0,19,27,55,78,8,17,40,78,90,4,30,58,77,80,2,20,33,51,69)
Percentage_prep4=c(2,30,45,77,90,0,3,15,40,55,4,11,28,44,50,7,19,33,47,68)
Percentage_prep5=c(0,19,27,55,78,8,17,40,78,90,4,30,58,77,80,2,20,33,51,69)
Percentage_prep6=c(5,10,20,40,60,1,20,30,50,70,2,15,22,43,66,10,40,60,80,89)
Percentage_prep7=c(0,19,27,55,78,8,17,40,78,90,4,30,58,77,80,2,20,33,51,69)
Percentage_prep8=c(5,10,20,40,60,1,20,30,50,70,2,15,22,43,66,10,40,60,80,89)
Percentage_prep9=c(5,10,20,40,60,1,20,30,50,70,2,15,22,43,66,10,40,60,80,89)
Percentage_prep10=c(0,37,61,72,98,1,9,22,55,77,0,8,25,33,58,1,29,43,51,69)
Percentage_prep11=c(2,30,45,77,90,0,3,15,40,55,4,11,28,44,50,7,19,33,47,68)
Percentage_prep12=c(0,19,27,55,78,8,17,40,78,90,4,30,58,77,80,2,20,33,51,69)
Percentage=c(Percentage_prep1,Percentage_prep2,Percentage_prep3,Percentage_prep4,Percentage_prep5,Percentage_prep6,
             Percentage_prep7,Percentage_prep8,Percentage_prep9,Percentage_prep10,Percentage_prep11,Percentage_prep12)

Quantile_prep=rep(c("Min","Q1","Med","Q3","Max"),4)
Quantile=rep(Quantile_prep,12)

Output_var_prep=rep(c("Out1","Out2"),each=60)
Output_var=rep(Output_var_prep,2)

rm(Parameters_base1,Parameters_base2,Par_val_prep1,Par_val_prep2,Par_val_prep3,Percentage_prep1,Percentage_prep2,Percentage_prep3,Percentage_prep4,Percentage_prep5,Percentage_prep6,
   Percentage_prep7,Percentage_prep8,Percentage_prep9,Percentage_prep10,Percentage_prep11,Percentage_prep12,Quantile_prep,Output_var_prep)

synthese=data.frame(Treatement=as.character(Treatement),
                    Parameters=as.character(Parameters),
                    Parameters_values=as.factor(Parameters_values),
                    Percentage=Percentage,
                    Quantile=as.character(Quantile),
                    Output_var=as.character(Output_var))
```

So in my data I  have 2 output variable (Out1 & 2) that vary in function of 3 parameters (A, B & C) each parameter have 4 values (1,2,3 & 4) and this for 2 cases (treatment: R2 & R6)
which gives data in this form (example, same thing for R2 and R6):

| Treatment | Parameters | Parameters_values | Percentage | Quantile | Output_var |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R2 | A | 1 | . | Min | Out1 |
| R2 | A | 1 | . | Q1 | Out1 |
| R2 | A | 1 | . | Med | Out1 |
| R2 | A | 1 | . | Q3 | Out1 |
| R2 | A | 1 | . | Max | Out1 |
| R2 | A | 2 | . | Min | Out1 |
| R2 | A | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | A | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | A | 3 | . | Min | Out1 |
| R2 | A | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | A | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | A | 4 | . | Min | Out1 |
| R2 | A | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | A | 1 | . | Min | Out2 |
| R2 | A | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | A | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | B | 1 | . | Min | Out1 |
| R2 | B | . | . | . | . |
| R2 | C | 1 | . | Min | Out1 |
| R2 | C | . | . | . | . |
| ...... | ... |  |  |  |  |
| ...... | ... |  |  |  |  |
| ...... | ... |  |  |  |  |
| R6 | A | 1 | . | Min | Out1 |
| ...... | ... | . | . | . | . |

So I would like to have a facet plot of output variable in function of parameters (for the 4 values) and this for the 2 cases in the same plot
Here is the example that I made with a geom_plot but I couldn't do the same with a boxplot:
Plot:
[image]

Code:

```
supp.labs <- c("A (%)", "B (°)", "C (m)")
names(supp.labs) <- c("A", "B", "C")
dose.labs <- c("Out put 1","Out put 2")
names(dose.labs) <- c("Out1", "Out2")



synthese %>% ggplot(aes(x=Parameters_values,y=Percentage,colour=Quantile, shape=Treatement))+
  #shape sert à donner differetnte formes selon la donnée cet exp y a que 2 années 
  # scale_y_continuous(name = "",
  #                    labels = (function(y) { paste(y, "%")}))+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "")+scale_x_discrete(name = "Simulated values for influencing parameters")+
  geom_point()+
  #facet_grid(bloc~traitement)
  facet_grid(Output_var~Parameters, margins = FALSE, scales = "free", shrink = TRUE,
             labeller = labeller(Output_var = dose.labs, Parameters = supp.labs))+
  guides(colour=guide_legend("Quantiles",title.position = "top"),
         shape=guide_legend("Treated row",title.position = "top"))+theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

```
supp.labs <- c("A (%)", "B (°)", "C (m)")
names(supp.labs) <- c("A", "B", "C")
dose.labs <- c("Out put 1","Out put 2")
names(dose.labs) <- c("Out1", "Out2")

synthese %>% ggplot(aes(x=Parameters_values,
                       y=Percentage,
                       colour=Treatement,
                       fill=Treatement))+
scale_y_continuous(name = "")+
scale_x_discrete(name = "Simulated values for influencing parameters")+
geom_boxplot(width=0.4,alpha=0.2)+
facet_grid(Output_var~Parameters,
             margins = FALSE,
             scales = "free", 
             shrink = TRUE,
             labeller = labeller(Output_var = dose.labs,
             Parameters = supp.labs))+
guides(fill=guide_legend("Treated row",title.position = "top"),
        colour=(show.legend=FALSE))+  # show only fill legend
theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

here is the result
[image]